# Center vertically and horizontally svg inside 2 div without adding props to parent div of svg

Tags: css, html, svg, flexbox

I have an svg inside a div and I need to center the svg both vertically and horizontally.
The problem is that width and height of the svg are getted using the library **[vx-responsive](https://github.com/hshoff/vx/tree/master/packages/vx-responsive)** so the resulting DOM is:

[image]

Edit: added the code

```
<div class="w-100 h-70 bg-yellow pa3 ba b--red flex flex-center center-vertical">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <svg width="41.59375" height="25.208">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="41.59375" height="25.208" stroke="green"></rect>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result is:

[image]

I can't remove the middle `div`, I need it but I can't add props to it.

What I can do to solve the problem?

Comment: copy and paste the code here

Comment: without inspecting its hard to tell, share your live link if possible

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple trick to center a HTML element:

```css
.w-100{
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
.w-100 div{
position:relative;
}
svg{
display:block;
margin:auto;
position:absolute;
top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="w-100 h-70 bg-yellow pa3 ba b--red flex flex-center center-vertical">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <svg width="41.59375" height="25.208">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="41.59375" height="25.208" stroke="green"></rect>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also you can read this article: [Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="w-100 h-70 bg-yellow pa3 ba b--red flex flex-center center-vertical">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <svg width="41.59375" height="25.208">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="41.59375" height="25.208" stroke="green"></rect>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

please use this code below:
--------------------------------

    <div class="w-100 h-70 bg-yellow pa3 ba b--red flex flex-center center-vertical">
        <svg width="41.59375" height="25.208">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="41.59375" height="25.208" stroke="green"></rect>
        </svg>
    </div>
--------------------------------

.w-100 {
  width: 100px;
}
.h-70 {
  height: 70px;
}
.bg-yellow {
  background:yellow;
}
.flex{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.flex-center {
  justify-content:center;
}
.center-vertical {
  align-items:center;
}
```